# oAuth Consent Screen Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to get the youtube channel name and the number of subscribers using the below code:

```
var youtubeAuthResponse = [],youtubeChannelResponse = [];
function authenticate() {
  showNewLoader('show');
  return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
  .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"})
  .then(function(response) {  
    console.log( response);
    youtubeAuthResponse['token_details'] = response.tc; 
    youtubeAuthResponse['google_email'] = '';
    youtubeAuthResponse['google_id'] = '';
    showNewLoader('hide');
  },
  function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); showNewLoader('hide');});
}
function loadClient() {
  showNewLoader('show');
  gapi.client.setApiKey("XXXX");
  return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
  .then(function() { execute();},
    function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err);showNewLoader('hide');});
}
/*Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.*/
function execute() {
  return gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
    "part": [
    "snippet",
    "statistics"
    ],
    "mine": true
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    /*Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).*/
    youtubeChannelResponse = response.result;
    storeYoutubeData();
  },
  function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); showNewLoader('hide') }).then(function(){
  });
}

gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
  gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "XXXXXX",
    'access_type':'offline'});
});
```

After signing in, I get the following error from google:

```
"The request uses the <code>mine</code> parameter but is not properly authorized."
```

Also the consent screen is never displayed.

[image]

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

@DaImTo

Comment: Do you have the correct scopes set in the youtube app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this was that I had already granted permission / consent to the scopes with the email address I have been trying.

Regardless of how much I tried after clearing cache and with different browsers the consent screen did not appear for that email address.

Using a new email address (youtube channel) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your scopes right?
Try this:

````
const response = await 
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels? 
part=snippet,statistic&mine=true&key=[API_KEY]",{
  " Authorization: Bearer `${accessToken}`"
}) //here just add bearer
}catch(error){
//err
}```
````

Comment: yes scopes are set. Please refer the above question.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `'prompt':'select_account'` after your access_type key.

```
gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
      gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "XXXXXX",
        'access_type':'offline',
        'prompt':'select_account'});
    });
```

Comment: still the same, no consent screen.